# in STM32F10, for instance, when i enable the Usart1 why doesnt the CUBEMX call HAL_GPIO_Init to set the alternate function of the corresponding pins?

Tags: arm, stm32, microcontroller, stm32cubemx

I just try to understand how the .ioc(cubemx) file respond to the configuration i set into my MCU and when i enable a peripheral lets say usart or whatsoever, it has to generate the code associated with setting the corresponding pins allocated to that specific peripheral(usart) but when i  check the code i cant find the section where it does (i tested for a gpio and set it as output and the cubemx just generated the code (HAL_GPIO_Init) )!!
how does it work?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gtk0c.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QymJA.png)

Where is the code associated with the Pin configuration?

Comment: cut and paste code, not pictures of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look in `Core/Src`, you should see a file called `stm32f1xx_hal_msp.c` or similar.

It will have a function in it called `HAL_UART_MspInit()`. This configures the GPIO pins used by your UART.

Comment: CubeMX is just a configurator for Cube, so if you intend to use it to set up a Cube/HAL program, you are supposed to be familiar with the Cube/HAL driver model, as described in Cube manual - in your case, CubeF1 manual [UM1850](https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/um1850-description-of-stm32f1-hal-and-lowlayer-drivers-stmicroelectronics.pdf), see chapter _3.12 How to use HAL drivers_, and _Figure 7. HAL driver model_ in there. That explains what @pmacfarlane said above.